# space on right side of bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, jsfiddle

I have been struggling with this carousel for hours now. I am learning bootstrap so excuse my code! :)

The problem is that my carousel has this "margin" on the right side that's not even there..
tried to googling after solutions but none works. It looks like this:
[idd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNU7q.jpg)

As you see the orange box on the right side of the carousel is what i'm trying to remove without luck.

My carousel code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="holder.js/1024x500" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">  <a class="btn btn-info">Download</a>

                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="item">
                     <img src="holder.js/1024x500" alt="...">
                     <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                 </div>
             </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a failed try on jsfiddle aswell (please don't mind the bugged jsfiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/2R4Ku/1/

Comment: You need to fix your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Feel so stupid now.. 
The "invisible" margin was a column:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
```

and i basically tried to "remove" col-8. 
well.. hopes this solves another beguinner's problem in the future ;)